# access variables from class constructor to the class functions in python

Tags: python

How to access variables from class constructor to the class functions?

Code:

```
class evol:
    k = 0
    m = 0

    def __init__(self, file1):
        InFile = open(file1, 'rb')
        InFile = csv.reader(InFile, delimiter='\t')
        for rec in InFile:
            self.k += int(rec[0])

    def method1():
        print k
```

I get the error,
NameError: global name 'k' is not defined

Comment: You need `def method(self): print self.k`. You may be familiar with other programming languages that use the `this` keyword, its basically that. `self` is just the convention to pass the reference of itself. You could also do `def method(self): print evol.k`. In python class variables can be accessed like that. In either case, the `method1` needs param `self` so that it knows its a `bound method` rather than a `static` or some other function

Comment: Thank you. When i access k in method1() using evol.k, it is printing initial value defined under class. However, using self.k, it print the modified value from constructor.

Comment: That is true. In Python a `class variable` will remain that value for the class and can be modified via the class. Since it doesn't have `self` as a reference as in `self.k = 12` under `__init__`, it doesn't know who it's referring to. That's why it's always better to initialize variables under `__init__`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the full name of the class variable:

```
def method1(self):
    print evol.k
```

or, since you assign to `self.k` in `__init__`, you might want

```
def method1(self):
    print self.k
```

instead, depending on which `k` you mean.

Comment: Thank you. When i access k in method1() using evol.k, it is printing initial value defined under class. However, using self.k, it print the modified value from constructor

Comment: As an aside, it's better to put `self.k = 0` in `__init__` if you want to provide a default value in case another value is not supplied later. Reserve class variables for things that are independent of instances, or truly shared by all instances.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough rep to add a comment, but are you sure you are indenting your code? Still, you can access to class variables using "self" keyword:

```
class evol:
    k = 0
    m = 0

    def __init__(self, file1):
        InFile = open(file1, 'rb')
        InFile = csv.reader(InFile, delimiter='\t')
        for rec in InFile:
            self.k += int(rec[0])

    def method1(self):
        print self.k
```

If you don't indent your code, method1() will be a standalone method outside the class, so it will not know anything about k

Comment: Thank you. I can not upvote this post as i have less reputation.